# Ant: Converting a path into separate properties

Tags: ant, properties, jar, classpath

I have a folder containing several jar files which should all go to a classpath:

```
<path id="my.classpath">
    <fileset dir="/tmp/mylibs" includes="*.jar" />
</path>
```

Now I would like to be able to reference all these jar files as a seperate property, 
e.g. if I have two jar files foo.jar and bar.jar then I would like to be able to reference them like

```
${foo.jar} (== /tmp/mylibs/foo.jar) 
${bar.jar} (== /tmp/mylibs/bar.jar)
```

Is that somehow possible in Ant?

Thanks, Peter

Comment: How you plan to know properties names?

Comment: For example they should simply be called like the name of the jar, so foo.jar ==> ${foo.jar}.
But actually I don't need the names, because I just need them to be properties so my .classpath file for Eclipse is written correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help of [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/for.html) you can try this:

```
<target name="test">
    <ac:for param="file">
        <fileset dir="/tmp/mylibs" includes="*.jar"/>
        <sequential>
                <antcall target="setImpl">
                    <param name="file" value="@{file}"/>
                </antcall>
                <echo>param: @{file}</echo>
        </sequential>
    </ac:for>
</target>

<target name="setImpl">
    <property name="filename" value="${file}" />
    <echo>property: ${filename}</echo>
</target>
```

For overriding property value (if you need) purpose you can also use [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html)

Comment: But then it's not a property?

Comment: Thanks for the hint! 
I actually dump all the jar files to a file and then use <loadproperties> to have them as property

Answer (score 0):

Ivy has a [artifactproperty](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/use/artifactproperty.html) task which is designed to do this for you.

The only catch to this solution is that it assumes you're using ivy to resolve your dependencies and manage your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to get the entire classpath into a single property:

```
<path id="my.classpath">
    <fileset dir="/tmp/mylibs" includes="*.jar" />
</path>

<property name="classpath.property" refid="my.classpath"/>

<echo message="Classpath = &quot;${classpath.property}&quot;"/>
```

I believe this will work in an Eclipse .classpath file. I don't have one in front of me right now. If you have to manipulate it, you can do that via the `<concat>` task with the filterchains.